# How to apply FILTER/MASK to an image in Firefox

Tags: html, css, filter

I have following code which works fine in IE and Google Chrome, I would like to know how to get the same filter/mask effect in Firefox :

<img style="FILTER:Alpha(opacity=50,style=2);-webkit-mask-box-image:-webkit-radial-gradient(white,transparent 50%); WIDTH: 800px; HEIGHT: 200px" src="http://i259.photobucket.com/albums/hh297/lilyyaxu/96264442052086857.gif?t=1334195033" />

Comment: What code? I don't see any code!

Comment: @aguyfromhere maybe that's why it's not working.  Firefox needs visible code.

Answer (score 0):

Try it without the `-webkit-` prefix. Only Safari, Chrome and I think Opera use those.

Comment: Thank you for replying, I tried without -webkit-, without success.